# Unit test and ordered tests - best practice

Tags: unit-testing, model-view-controller

I've got a complex part of a web application, and we're starting now to unit test it in order to ensure that everything works fine, and if any changes will be made, the tests will be there to check whether we broke anything.

This portion of our app is a sort of wizard: You go from step 1 to step N. Each step can fork in different ways depending on what the user chooses. Each step can also contain either only 1 item or a collection of items, like this:

- Step 1: Are there items of type X? If yes, how many?

  - For each item declared -> form to input item data
- Step 2: Are there items of type Y? If yes, how many?

  - For each item declared -> form to input item data (may contain references to items declared in step 1)

etc. It's not all like this, there are exceptions, but it's just to give an idea of how it is. Now this procedure isn't forward-only. The user must be able to jump back to previous nodes and apply changes, add items or remove items from collections, etc. and the software must remember what was the last step he completed before jumping back, so when he's done he can go on.

For unit testing purposes, I am thinking that I can't have standalone tests: if you haven't completed previous steps, you don't have the data for successive steps. Thus I was thinking of writing ordered tests.

I also read that a best practice is to "have the test be independent from one another", and what I thought to do is going against this.

The sample tests I wrote are green if run as an ordered test, but only the first one is green if run as standalone tests.

Now I'd like to hear opinions and if anyone has a correct way to approach this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each test should indeed be independent of each other. If Test B depends on Test A executing before it, then you have potentially very flakey tests on your hands. In your situation, I'd prefer to `SetUp` Test B by pre-configuring a context.

What I mean is, whatever state Test A leaves the system after it has completed, use that to setup the context for Test B e.g.

```
public void TestB()
{
    // Arrange.
    SetupSystemLikeTestAHadJustRun();

   // Act.
   // Do your tests.

   // Assert.
}
```

By having a known, fixed, context at the start of the test, you stand a much better chance of having a good suite of tests.

Alternatively, if you have heard of BDD (Behaviour Driven Development) you could a use a BDD tool like SpecFlow or NBehave (for .NET) or Cucumber for Ruby. Using BDD allows you to be more expressive in your testing.

Comment: I was imagining something like this. My concern is, since this wizard is very large and many stuff is needed in later steps, that my tests would become larger and larger as I test further steps. Any thoughts about this?

Comment: Then I would go the BDD route. By writing your tests out in a Given, When, Then fasion, you can easily read the steps involved with a scenario test. Have you done BDD before? Also, what environment are you using - .NET?

Comment: .Net 4.0 Visual Studio 2010 and Mvc3. Using MsTests right now although I could switch to nunit or something else if needed.

Answer (score 1):

**Do's and Don'ts**
**DO**

Name tests with both their expected outcome and relevant details of the state or input being tested

**DON'T**

Give tests names that say nothing beyond the name of the method being tested except in trivial cases

**STRUCTURE**

**Structure tests in three distinct blocks - arrange, act, and assert.**

Unit tests tend to have a very regular structure. A common way to refer to this structure is arrange, act, assert: every test must arrange the state of the world to test, act on the class under test by calling methods, and assert that the world is in the expected state afterward.

The arrange block is for setting up details of the external world specific to the situation under test. This involves things like creating local variables that will be reused in the test, and sometimes instantiating the object under test with specific arguments. This step should not involve any calls to the object under test (do that during the act block) or verifications of initial state (do that during assert, maybe in another test). Note that general setup required by all or many tests should be done in the test's setUp method. If your test doesn't depend on any specific external state, you can skip the arrange block.

The act block is where you actually make calls to the class under test to trigger the behavior that is being tested. Frequently this block will be a single method call, but if the behavior you're testing spans several methods then they will each be called here. Simple arguments can be inlined as part of the method call, but more complex argument expressions are sometimes better off extracted to the arrange block to avoid distracting from the intent of the block. The act block may also assign a method's return value to a local variable so that it can be asserted on later.

The assert block is the place to make assertions on the return values collected and to verify any interactions with mock objects. It can also build values required for the assertions and verifications. In very simple tests, the act and assert blocks are sometimes combined by inlining calls on the class under test into an assert statement.

These blocks should be distinct from one another - the test should not perform any additional setup or stubbing once it makes calls to the class under test in the act block, and it should not make further calls to the class under test once verification begins in the assert block.

It should be clear when glancing at the test where each block starts and ends. Usually this can be done by adding a single blank line between each block (though this isn't necessary in simple tests where the blocks are only one or two lines each). In particularly complex tests, especially ones where you have to set up several different objects, you might want to use blank lines within blocks to make them more readable. In this case, one option to distinguish the blocks is to label each with a comment like // Arrange, // Act, and // Assert.

Tests that emphasize this structure are clearer since they make it easy to navigate different parts of the test, and more likely to be complete since the regular structure helps ensure that the details of the behavior being tested aren't hidden or omitted.

Mocking frameworks interact with this structure in different ways. Most modern frameworks like Mockito allow stubs to be configured in the arrange block along with defining local variables, and mocks to be verified in the assert block along with performing assertions. Some older frameworks like EasyMock unfortunately require the expected behaviors of mocks to be specified before invoking the code under test - this requires a fourth "expect" block before the act block which works in a similar way to the assert block.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a tool like cucumber or selenium to test the graphical stuff you describe. You can use a unit test framework like junit and nunit to write these kind of tests, but these doesn't really support running ordered tests.

Comment: We are considering "graphical testing", simulating the user for a next step. For now, we're testing the mvc controller/actions with normal unit tests and mocks. My question is about how to properly organize this.